# Multiple choice questions - are they always leading?

Tags: surveys

I'm designing a survey in which I want to know what kind of problems with my software my users have.

I wonder if I should create one big open-text question? Or should I suggest some answers and go with multiple options question (with an open-text answer at the end?).

Personally, I prefer the multiple options version. I think that by giving examples, it'll help my users to come up with their own ideas.

What's your opinion?

Comment: This will always depend on the case, your question is too broad and vague. However, if you're looking for issues in your software, I don't think a multiple choice survey is the best option. Then again, it depends on many factors

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. As for the question being too broad, I want my users to simply list all issues and problems they can think of when using my software. I see, though, that if the question itself is more precise I might get better answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the data you want. Is it qualitative or quantitative? And that depends on how you are planning to measure the results. Since there is not much clear it is hard to give real advice. For quantitive data however you probably want just multiple choice since that is easier to process.

If you want to collect qualitative data, use multiple choice with an "other" option. When "other" is checked show a text field near it to allow users to fill in the alternative. Give that field a clear label with some instructions about what you want to know, and give it enough space to leave a full explanation with examples. The field should be close to the option as it is part of the question.

Only if one of the preset answers (not "other") is checked show a new question below to give an explanation and examples. This is a separate question and should have the same distance from the options as there is space between any questions. Since the question is separate, refer back to the previous one with clear instructions about what you want to know. Simplified example: "As preferred color for your new car you answered: Blue. Can you explain why you prefer that color?".

There are multiple ways to achieve the same but the one above provides two paths and doesn't confuse the user with two text fields when choosing "other".

1. As a user...

- I don't see my preferred choice, but since there is "other" I choose that
- I clicked "other" and I can now fill in my preferred choice noting that they also want me to explain it

2. As a user...

- I click my preferred choice and move on to the next question
- I read the next question and it asks me to explain my choice above

Comment: Great explanation. I want to add 2 other things:
1. As a user, it's easier for me to check a box (option) than writing text, especially if I'm on a mobile or a tablet.
2. As the owner, it's easier to analyze, sort or a apply any kind of data visualization/analysis when you have predefined options. When you have large text areas and a lot of feedback from different users, you have to go 1-by-1 and read them manually.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you another idea, maybe it helps you.

If you gather quantitative data (pre-defined choices), you will anchor the users choice to the presented options and get information as general as it can be.

If you gather qualitative data (free text), you will most probably gather less responses, harder to analyse, but closer to what your users think.

You can try a simple combination of NPS like question ("How likely is it that you would recommend this software to a friend or collegue?" | 1 → 10 rating | [details here](https://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/net-promoter-score/)) for a general quantitative measure and a split qualitative measure like "Pros of my software", "Cons of my software" and "I need this in order to use this software more" in order to inspire them to write something much closer to what they have in their minds.

Also, it doesn't hurt to put a checkbox at the end with "I'm ok with being contacted via email for more feedback". 1:1 conversation can give you another level of feedback.

Your choice needs to balance out (from the top of my mind):

- how many users are you expecting to answer (ex: the more you have, the more people you will need to analyse qualitative data (or ML?) )
- how actionable you want your feedback
- what are you going to do with it (ex: to track changes in time, same quantitative data captured periodically will give you better answers than qualitative. the trend would be more important that the value itself)

Answer (score 0):

Both. You can have open-ended questions to capture things that don't fit neatly into any category. But generally, I would prefer specific questions that are easily answered. For example, How easy is it to find what you're looking for on this software? Which page did you have trouble on while attempting to: -your use case here- ? Then you can focus on those specific issues, modules or pages.

If you ask people non specific questions about your software, you will get non specific answers. For example what do you like or dislike about the software? They might say something generic which you can't do anything about or is just one person's opinion.